# NPOI Excel Format not working

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I have a function that is generating an Excel file using the NPOI Library. Witch for the most part is working fine just got a problem with style's they seem to function dodgy. Currently my focus is the number formats:

I would like all decimals to display as: 12.156.235,33 for example

According to the reserach on google the format that should do that should be: "#,##0.00" but the value shows up as: 12156235,33 and the cell type is set to general instead of number

It also looks like alot of people have problems with this. Hope there is a solution cos everything else I whanted to do I managed with the NPOI library and would not whant to switch now.

The procedure:

```
IDataFormat dataFormat;
public string GenerateExcel(ExcelData data)
{
    var dateFormat = dataFormat.GetFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    var decimalFormat = dataFormat.GetFormat("#,##0.00");       

    string xlsPath, xlsFile, xlsName;
    xlsPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP");
    xlsName = Path.GetRandomFileName().Replace(".", ""); //DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    xlsName += ".xlsx";
    xlsFile = Path.Combine(xlsPath, xlsName);
    if (File.Exists(xlsFile))
        File.Delete(xlsFile);
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    dataFormat = workbook.CreateDataFormat();
    XSSFCellStyle style = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
    NPOI.SS.UserModel.ICell cell;
    Dictionary<int, int> maxColSize = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    string title;
    int rr;
    foreach (var sheet in data.Sheets)
    {
        maxColSize.Clear();
        if(sheet.Hidden != null)
            foreach (var h in sheet.Hidden)
            {
                sheet.HideRow(h);
            }

        worksheet = (XSSFSheet)workbook.CreateSheet(sheet.Title);
        rr = 0;
        if (sheet.Titles!=null && sheet.Titles.Length > 0)
        {
            worksheet.CreateRow(rr);
            rr++;
            for (int t = 0; t < sheet.Titles.Length; t++)
            {
                title = (string)sheet.Titles[t].Title;
                maxColSize.Add(t, title.Length);
                cell = worksheet.GetRow(0).CreateCell(t, NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.String);
                cell.SetCellValue(title);
                if (sheet.Titles[t].Style != null)
                    cell.CellStyle = GetCellStyle(sheet.Titles[t].Style);
            }
        }
        int cols = 0;
        int cc = 0;
        IRow row = null;
        for (int r = 0; r < sheet.Rows.Length; r++)
        {
            if (sheet.Rows[r].row > -1)
            {
                rr = sheet.Rows[r].row;
                row = worksheet.GetRow(sheet.Rows[r].row);
            }
            else
            {
                //rr = r;
                row = worksheet.GetRow(rr);
            }


            if (row == null)
            {
                row = worksheet.CreateRow(rr);
            }                   

            if(sheet.Rows[r].Cells.Length > cols)
                cols = sheet.Rows[r].Cells.Length;

            for (int c = 0; c < sheet.Rows[r].Cells.Length;c++ )
            {


                cc = c;

                if (sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].column > -1)
                {
                    cc = sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].column;
                }
                if (!maxColSize.Keys.Contains(cc))
                    maxColSize.Add(cc, 0);

                switch (sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].DataType)
                {
                    case "DateTime":
                        cell = row.CreateCell(cc, NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.Numeric);
                        cell.SetCellValue((DateTime)sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value);
                        cell.CellStyle.DataFormat = dateFormat;
                        if (maxColSize[cc] < cell.NumericCellValue.ToString().Length)
                            maxColSize[cc] = cell.NumericCellValue.ToString().Length;
                        break;
                    case "Numeric":
                    case "Decimal":
                        cell = row.CreateCell(cc, NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.Numeric);
                        cell.SetCellValue(Convert.ToDouble(sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value)); //sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value
                        cell.CellStyle.DataFormat = decimalFormat;
                        if (maxColSize[cc] < cell.NumericCellValue.ToString().Length)
                            maxColSize[cc] = cell.NumericCellValue.ToString().Length;
                        break;
                    case "Integer":
                        cell = row.CreateCell(cc, NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.Numeric);
                        cell.SetCellValue(Convert.ToInt32(sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value));
                        cell.CellStyle.DataFormat = dataFormat.GetFormat("0");
                        if (maxColSize[cc] < cell.NumericCellValue.ToString().Length)
                            maxColSize[cc] = cell.NumericCellValue.ToString().Length;
                        break;
                    case "Date":
                        cell = row.CreateCell(cc, NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.Numeric);
                        cell.SetCellValue((DateTime)sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value);
                        cell.CellStyle.DataFormat = dataFormat.GetFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
                        if (maxColSize[cc] < cell.NumericCellValue.ToString().Length)
                            maxColSize[cc] = cell.NumericCellValue.ToString().Length;
                        break;
                    case "Boolean":
                        cell = row.CreateCell(cc, NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.Boolean);
                        cell.SetCellValue(Convert.ToBoolean(sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value));
                        if (maxColSize[cc] < cell.BooleanCellValue.ToString().Length)
                            maxColSize[cc] = cell.StringCellValue.ToString().Length;
                        break;
                    case "Formula":
                        cell = row.CreateCell(cc, NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.Formula);
                        cell.SetCellFormula((string)(sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value));
                        if (maxColSize[cc] < cell.BooleanCellValue.ToString().Length)
                            maxColSize[cc] = cell.StringCellValue.ToString().Length;
                        break;
                    default:
                        cell = row.CreateCell(cc, NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.String);
                        cell.SetCellValue((string)sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value);
                        if (maxColSize[cc] < cell.StringCellValue.Length)
                            maxColSize[cc] = cell.StringCellValue.Length;
                        break;
                }
                if (sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].Style != null)
                {
                    var st = GetCellStyle(sheet.Rows[r].Cells[c].Style);                               
                    cell.CellStyle = st;
                }

            }


            if (sheet.Rows[r].row == -1)
                rr++;

            if(sheet.Merge != null)
                foreach (var merge in sheet.Merge)
                {
                    worksheet.AddMergedRegion( new NPOI.SS.Util.CellRangeAddress(merge.FirstRow,merge.LastRow, merge.FirstColumn, merge.LastColumn));
                }                    
        }

        foreach (var col in maxColSize)
        {
            worksheet.SetColumnWidth(col.Key, ((int)(col.Value * 1.14388)) * 256);
        }
        XSSFFormulaEvaluator.EvaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);
    }
    using (var fs = new FileStream(xlsFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        workbook.Write(fs);
    }

    return xlsFile;
}
```

Comment: Switched to EPPlus. Works better for what I need

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NPOI formats all cells the same way](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40308711/10263)